# Scala Trait Mixin order

Tags: scala

```
object sandbox {

  class Numbers {
    def price() : List[Int] = List(1,3,5,7)
    def printIt(): Unit = {
      price.foreach(x => print(x+ " ") )
    }
  }

  trait DoubleIt extends Numbers {
    override def price() : List[Int] ={
      println("doubling")
      super.price.map(x => x*2)
    }
  }

  trait AddIt extends Numbers {
    override def price() : List[Int] = {
      println("adding")
      super.price.map( x => x+2)
    }
  }

  def main(args :Array[String]): Unit = {
    val obj = new Numbers with DoubleIt with AddIt
    obj.printIt() 
  }

}
//output :
adding
doubling
4 8 12 16
```

In the above code, `price()` method from `AddIt` trait executes first (from print statement).But shouldn't the value be `6 10 14 18`? Why the values are doubled before adding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your traits are stacked in the order that you declare them:

AddIt

DoubleIt

Numbers

When you run printIt, you're doing it on an AddIt, resulting in the following call chain:

```
AddIt.printIt
AddIt.printIt.price       //here you get to print "adding"
AddIt.price.super.price   //calls DoubleIt's price
DoubleIt.price            //here you get to print "doubling"
DoubleIt.super.price      //calls Number's price
Numbers.price             //returns List(1, 3, 5, 7)
DoubleIt.super.price.map  //doubles your list input
AddIt.super.price.map     //adds 2 to the result
AddIt.printIt.foreach     //prints the final result
```

Answer (score 5):

The result makes sense:

1. `printIt` calls `AddIt.price`
2. `AddIt.price` calls `DoubleIt.price`, and *then* adds 2 to each one
3. `DoubleIt.price` calls `Numbers.price`, and then dubles each one, returning `List(2,6,10,14)`
4. This means that `AddIt.price` returns `List(2+2, 6+2, 10+2, 14+2)`, which is indeed the printed result

The key here is understanding that indeed `AddIt.price` *starts* before `DoubleIt.price`, but it uses the result of `DoubleIt.price` to create the return value, *before* the addition.